# Iterating and replacing over columns and rows with multiple values

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, lambda, replace, iteration

I have a dataframe with a column that contains ids. I need to replace these ids with  names from a dictionary (ids = keys). I add a new column using this method:

```
df['Names'] = df['Ids'].apply(lambda x: (next(v for k, v in dict.items() if k in x))
```

And  it   works well  in the lines with a single value (0-13). But in the lines with  several values (rows 14-20)  only one value is replaced and I get  this:

```
        Ids               Names
0   1                       MSA
1   1                       MSA
2   1                       MSA
3   1                       MSA
4   1                       MSA
5   1                       MSA
6   1                       MSA
7   10174                    LO
8   10174                    LO
9   10174                    LO
10  10174                    LO
11  10174                    LO
12  10174                    LO
13  10174                    LO
14  225, -1, -10174, 977    -MSA
15  225, -1, -10174, 977    -MSA
16  225, -1, -10174, 977    -MSA
17  225, -1, -10174, 977    -MSA
18  225, -1, -10174, 977    -MSA
19  225, -1, -10174, 977    -MSA
20  225, -1, -10174, 977    -MSA
```

How to replace  all  ids in lines 14-20?
For the rows 14-20 I expect output like "KR, -MSA, -LO, SHB". Thanks

Comment: What would be the expected output in the for row 14?  A list of corresponding values in the `Names` column?  Any reason you don't "flatten" the list and turn things like row 14 into 4 entries, which would be much cleaner?

Comment: Hi, for the rows 14-20  I expect  output  like "KR, -MSA, -LO, SHB". 
I would not like to break the columns into 4 entries because for the final large dataframe I have to join them back. This way  will add steps  I'd like to avoid  if it possible...